# convert list elements into list of lists

Tags: python, list

Simple question .
How would you convert a list like this :

```
["foo","banana","apple"]
```

into

```
[["foo"],["banana"],["apple"]]
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is there any approach you have tried so far? If not, why not? If yes, please post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> [[el] for el in ["foo","banana","apple"]]
[['foo'], ['banana'], ['apple']]
```

Comment: As a note, this is a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), the best way to build up a list from the modified elements of another list.